# WP_Query Is Not function correctly

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm writing a wp theme, for that I just want to make a wrapper function around WP_Query and reuse it. for simplify life.

my wrapper function is:

```
//for making wp_query easily
    function myQuery($options,$callback){
        $the_query = new WP_Query($options);
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
                $the_query->the_post(); 
                $callback();
           }            
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        wp_reset_query();
    }


//get a single post by the id.
function get_post_by_id($id,$callback){     
     $options = array('post_in' => $id, );
     myQuery($options,$callback);
}
```

but when i use the `get_post_by_id()` function, I get unexpected Result, I notice that the callback is called for multiple time.

How can i fix this ?????

Answer (score 0):

The correct option that you should be using is `post__in` and not `post_in`. Since you are not sending correct options, wp_query is returing all posts and hence multiple callback calls.

Comment: Well, did you try `post__in`? Did it work? If you were not using the wrapper function, where/how were you calling these codes?